# Vue render props in component in slot

Tags: vue.js, components, slot, vue-props

I have two components:

in first component (`FirstComponent.vue`) I have:

```vue
    <RightModal>
        <span slot="body">
            {{ worker }}
            <input type="checkbox" @click="selectCheckbox(worker.id)">
        </span>
    </RightModal>
```

```js
    props: {
        worker: {
            type: Object,
            required: true,
        },
    },
```

```js
    selectCheckbox( id ) {
        this.$root.$emit('runShowWorker', id);
    },
```

In `SecondComponent.vue` I have:

```vue
    mounted() {
        this.$root.$on('runShowWorker', id => {
            showWorker(id)
            .then(res => {
                this.worker = res.data;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
            });
        });
    },
```

to `this.worker` I send new data from database. I send this data using props:

In `SecondComponent.vue`:

```vue
    <FirstComponent :worker="worker" />
```

I have a problem with `worker` in `FirstComponent.vue`. I send new data but this props not rendering. How I can fix it ?

EDIT:

If I try push null data: `.then(res => { this.worker = null })`.
Then I have error:

> Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "worker". Expected Object,
>   got Null

but in page data for worker not disapear.

Comment: Can you replicate this in a codepen or similar?

Comment: 1. Do you see any errors in the console? 2. Is `worker` defined as a `data` property of `SecondComponent`? 3. If you put `console.log(res.data);` immediately before the line `this.worker = res.data;` do you see the correct data being logged?

Comment: @skirtle No i don't have an aerros. worker in SecondComponent is only defined in props. yes I have a correctly data in console.log(res.data). I edit my query

Comment: I think you're going to have to construct a [mcve].